# Using QueryPerformanceCounter at Intervals in VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, performancecounter, timing

I was wondering if I could somehow get some guidance on using QueryPerformanceCounter/Frequency on performing a task at every interval in VB.NET. Let's say for example every 6 micro-second.

I was thinking maybe find the time now and do a mod on 6us, but there would lead to precision issues?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: The performance counter methods aren’t really suited as a timer but rather to measure durations. And you don’t need to use them directly via WinAPI calls, they are provided in the .NET framework via the `StopWatch` class.

Comment: Thank you I was actually confused by as to what QPC really was. This cleared up a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a "timer-class" that stores the previous time and interval. Then create a method like Update(). In that method you check the current time of something like a stopwatch and compare it with the previous time and the interval. If you are to early just sleep the rest of the time. Thats princip of games are working.